# Can't construct URL for phone call in Swift

Tags: swift, url, phone-number

I'm trying to ask for phone call programmatically but I'm not able to construct URL from my nine-digit phone number. When I try it with for example 999999999 phone number, it works, it asks for call

```
@IBAction func callButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    askForCall(to: "999999999")
}

func askForCall(to number: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "tel:\(number)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

but when I use real phone number 736XXXXXX it shows nothing.

**Note:** when I try it without canOpenUrl it doesn’t work so I guess problem is with constructing URL from my real number

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I have solved it, but the problem was not with bad numbers or bad method. Problem was that I copied my phone number from another place in my code and passed it as a parameter when I called this method. And from some reason when I had deleted the last digit and had written it manually it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You should type `"tel://" + number` and not `tel:\(number)`

**EDIT 2**

Try something like this

```
func call(phoneNumber: String) {
    if let url = URL(string: phoneNumber) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
                                  completionHandler: {
                                    (success) in
                                    print("Open \(phoneNumber): \(success)")
            })
        } else {
            let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            print("Open \(phoneNumber): \(success)")
        }
    }
} 


let number = "736XXXXXX"

let phoneNumber = "tel://\(number)"
call(phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
```

Try with that number to see if it's a bigger problem than the simple code :)

Comment: try to remove UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)

Comment: Wait! Are you trying on simulator or on a real device??

Comment: If I remove it it returns too because problem is with constructing URL I guess. Also if I removed it I wouldn't be able to open URL so, this won't solve anything. And yes, I'm running my app on real device (I'm able to askForCall with non-existent phone number).

Comment: Yeah my bad sorry, canOpen should be there to prevent error, but try your application on a true device, sometimes on the simulator won't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to write real device (not simulator).

Comment: This also doesn't work and this doesn't work even with non-existent number

Comment: I really don't know! Because it always worked to me :/
In my application the url "tel://+393400000000" works

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scheme 'tel' into your info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
      <string>tel</string>
```

Then normal use:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {return}
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
```

Goodluck